# Conditional probability with multiple dependent conditions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes

A set of items is said to be incorrect if at least one item in the set is incorrect. 
Initially, all items have equal probability of being correct/incorrect (P = 0.5).
A series of infinite events start.
Assume these sample events: 
{a,b,c,d} incorrect
{a,b} incorrect
{c} correct
.
.
And so forth.
How do I update the probability of each item being incorrect given all events up to date?
That is, for example: P(a| {a,b,c,d}) after the first event, P(a| {a,b,c,d}, {a,b}) after the second event, P(a| {a,b,c,d}, {a,b}, {c}) after the third event, ...
You could see that these events are actually also dependent. I mean that if {a,b} is incorrect, then {a,b,c,d} is surely incorrect too.
It would be really great if someone could show me how to derive the probability of a being incorrect for these 3 events.
Thank you.